# Computing a function for a sequence of numbers (-1, 1/8, -1/27, 1/64, ...)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I've got a sequence ${-1 , 1/8 , -1/27, 1/64, ... }$ and I'm confused about the $-1$ and $-1/27$.

I've deduced that the function for this series would be something like $f(n) = 1/n^3$ starting at $n=1$; however, I run into the issue of the first value being a positive $1$ instead of negative.

I'm confused about how to alter the function in order to basically get the same values but keep the first value (the $-1$) actually negative.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

edit:

A little clarity, right now my series is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3}$ but this gives me ${1, 1/8, 1/27, 1/64}$ instead of a $-1$ and $-1/27$.

edit 2:

## Direct Question Wording

Consider the series: $-1 + \frac{1}{8} - \frac{1}{27} + \frac{1}{64} - ...$

Explain why the series converges, and estimate it's sum so that the error is less than $.005$.

Comment: Do you want to make polynomial?

Comment: Why not 
$$
\begin{cases}
-1 & \text{if } n=1 \\
\frac{1}{n^3} & \text{if } n > 1
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: but wouldn't $1/1^3$ just be $1$? @Zubzub

Comment: I basically am trying to make $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n^3$ make sense.

Comment: You can always rewrite $-1 + 1/8 + 1/27 + ...$ as $-2 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3}$ if you really want. (Or even $\zeta(3) -2$).

Comment: @Zubzub Clearly I'm confused. Is there no way to rewrite $\frac{1}{n^3}$ where when $n = 1$ the value is a negative 1?

Comment: I don't know what the context of this series is, but if it showed up in a homework assignment, I'd be double- and triple-checking for sign errors.

Comment: If you really want you can say something like $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n-3/2}{|n-3/2|} \frac{1}{n^3}$.

Comment: @ConnorHarris I've added the question in the original post.

Comment: Is there a reason you've taken an alternating sum $-1 + 1/8 - 1/27 + 1/64 - \cdots$ and dropped all negative signs besides the first?

Comment: @ConnorHarris To be honest I misread the signs in that question. I'm actually more confused now because my function is no longer valid.

Comment: Now that you edited, this is clearly $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^3}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no useful way to modify $\frac{1}{n^3}$ to suit. The best approach is to just list the first term as an exception. For example, if you want a sum, the series can be written as $-1 + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{27} + \frac{1}{64} + \cdots = -1 + \sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^3}$. The idea is that we just drop the $n = 1$ term from the series and replace it with the $-1$ at the front.

A word of caution: This sort of series is unlikely to happen naturally. If you constructed the sequence yourself - for example, by taking derivatives of a function or something similar - check to make sure that the $\frac{1}{27}$ isn't supposed to be $-\frac{1}{27}$. An alternating sequence would be much easier to characterize.

Comment: You're right, the sequence is actually $-1 + 1/8 - 1/27 + 1/64 - ...$

Comment: I've accepted your answer since it actually solved my problem for the most part; however, the reply on my original post solves the new problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the correct question, your sum is $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac {(-1)^k}{k^3}$  This is an alternating series with terms converging to zero, so you know it converges.  You know the error in the partial sums is less than the first neglected term so you can stop adding after $\frac {-1}{125}$ and be done.